# What is the state of a TCP socket after remote closed?

Tags: sockets, tcp, solaris, netstat

Say I have accepted() a connection to my server (that runs on a Solaris) and the client has closed the connection. What is the state of the socket (in netstat categories) of the socket on the server side before I close() it on the server side? Is it BOUND?

Answer (score 7):

It will be CLOSE_WAIT, see the tcp state diagram, e.g. on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tcp_state_diagram_new.svg

Answer (score 1):

In this situation the socket on the client will be in TIME_WAIT and the socket on the server will go through CLOSE_WAIT and will move to CLOSED pretty quickly so you might not catch it in netstat before it vanishes from the list altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `CLOSE_WAIT` since the end which intiates `FIN` goes to `TIME_WAIT` ---> `CLOSED` first.

In this it's the client which initiates first. So the server will go to `CLOSE_WAIT`.

Answer (score 0):

CLOSE_WAIT

you can check by:

ps auxf

lsof -a -p [server_process_id]

you will get:  sock 0,8

state 8:  TCP_CLOSE

Answer (score -1):

I guess, TIME_WAIT.

You may check it with "netstat" on Linux, don't know how do it on Solaris.

Comment: No, TIME_WAIT is _after_ socket is closed() on the local end. I asked about state before closing() the descriptor.